# Need Help to resolve : could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, hibernate3

Below is the stacktrace of the error:

org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:240)

Below is my POJO class :

```
public static final class MemberName implements java.io.Serializable
    {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3832626162173359411L;
        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;
        private String gender;
        private String dexterity;
        private String matchPreference;
        private String tournamentEntry;
        /*private Double rating;
        private Double minRating=Double.valueOf(2.5);
        private Double maxRating=Double.valueOf(5.0);*/
        private Integer rating=null;
        private Integer minRating=null;
        private Integer maxRating=Integer.valueOf(5);
        private Integer maxHandicap = Integer.valueOf(100);//Integer.valueOf(6);
        private Integer minHandicap = null;

        public MemberName() {
        }

        public String getFirstname() { return this.firstname; }
        public void setFirstname(String name) { this.firstname = name; }

        public String getLastname() { return this.lastname; }
        public void setLastname(String name) { this.lastname = name; }

        public Integer getMaxHandicap() { return this.maxHandicap; }
        public void setMaxHandcap(Integer d) { this.maxHandicap = d; }

        public Integer getMinHandicap() { return this.minHandicap; }
        public void setMinHandcap(Integer d) { this.minHandicap = d; }

        public String getGender() { return this.gender;}
        public void setGender(String gender) {this.gender = gender;}

        public String getDexterity() {return this.dexterity;}
        public void setDexterity(String dexterity) {this.dexterity = dexterity;}

        public String getMatchPreference() {return this.matchPreference;}
        public void setMatchPreference(String matchPreference) {this.matchPreference = matchPreference;}

        public String getTournamentEntry() {return this.tournamentEntry;}
        public void setTournamentEntry(String tournamentEntry) {this.tournamentEntry = tournamentEntry;}

        public Integer getRating() {return this.rating;}
        public void setRating(Integer r) {this.rating = r;}

        public Integer getMinRating() {return this.minRating;}
        public void setMinRating(Integer minR) {this.minRating = minR;}

        public Integer getMaxRating() {return this.maxRating;}
        public void setMaxRating(Integer maxR) {this.maxRating = maxR;}

        public boolean isValidSearch()
        {
            return (null != this.firstname) ||
                    (null != this.lastname) ||
                    (null != this.maxRating) ||
                    (null != this.minRating)||
                    (null != this.rating)||
                    (null != this.gender) ||
                    (null != this.dexterity) ||
                    (null != this.matchPreference)||
                    (null != this.tournamentEntry);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MemberName [firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname="
                    + lastname + ", gender=" + gender + ", dexterity="
                    + dexterity + ", matchPreference=" + matchPreference
                    + ", tournamentEntry=" + tournamentEntry + ", rating="
                    + rating + ", minRating=" + minRating + ", maxRating="
                    + maxRating + "]";
        }
    }
```

and I'm using hibernate 3 to fetch the data from User table which is a hibernate pojo class-

```
public List<User> findUsers(Long cityId, String firstName, String 
        lastName,
            String gender, Double rating, Double minRating, Double maxRating,
            String dexterity, String matchPreference, String tournamentEntry) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (null != cityId) {
            sb.append("u.registeredCity.id=").append(cityId).append(" "); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
        }
        if (isNotEmpty(firstName)) {
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append("and "); //$NON-NLS-1$
            }
            sb.append("u.firstName like '").append(firstName).append("%' "); 
        }
        if (isNotEmpty(lastName)) {
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append("and "); //$NON-NLS-1$
            }
            sb.append("u.lastName like '").append(lastName).append("%'"); 
        }

        sb.append(" order by u.firstName, u.lastName");

        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.insert(0, "where "); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        sb.insert(0, "from User u "); //$NON-NLS-1$

        this.log.info("SQL from findUsers method is::"+sb.toString());
        return getHibernateTemplate().find(sb.toString());

    }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this post @Piyush